# how to save uploaded image twice at two dirs in yii?

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I want to assign a file field input for two variables, and then I want to save this two variables into two different dirs, here is my code:

controller:

```
if(isset($_POST['Articles']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Articles'];
                        $model->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $model->display = 1;
                        $model->visits = 0;
                        $model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
                        $model->thumbnail = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            if($model->save()){

                            if(!empty($model->image)){

                                $model->image->saveAs(getcwd()."/images/articles/".$model->image);
                                if(!empty($model->thumbnail))
                                if(!$model->thumbnail->saveAs(getcwd()."\images\articles\thumbnails/".$model->thumbnail))
                                $thumbnail = Yii::app()->image->load(getcwd()."/images/articles/thumbnails/".$model->thumbnail);
                                $thumbnail->resize(64, 64);
                                $thumbnail->save();
                            }

                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                        }
```

after saving model, the thumbnails dir still empty, and I am getting an error from the image extension that there is no file to be loaded, so how I can save this image twice in the two dirs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need 2 instances of 2 images, by default saveAs deletes temp file, so your could do smthing like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Articles']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Articles'];
        $model->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->display = 1;
        $model->visits = 0;
        $model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        if($model->save()){
            if(!empty($model->image)){
                 $model->image->saveAs(getcwd()."/images/articles/".$model->image,false);//here's a trick
                 if($model->image->saveAs(getcwd()."\images\articles\thumbnails/".$model->image) {
                       $thumbnail = Yii::app()->image->load(getcwd()."/images/articles/thumbnails/".$model->image);
                       $thumbnail->resize(64, 64);
                       $thumbnail->save();
                 }

                 $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }
```

You could also do it without saving image, then loading again - do it on the fly, for ex. EUploadedImage.